# Reducing multi body system to a single body using reduced mass

Tags: classical-mechanics

A two body system can be treated as a single body using reduced mass and the motion can be described using one generalized coordinate.
Can this concept be somehow used to reduce a body of say 3 or more particles to a single body?

Comment: i was thinking about using continued fractions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two dof of the system reduces to one because the other one ends up with constant velocity solution and a co-moving reference frame can be constructed that is still inertial. For three bodies, no such co-moving inertial frame exists.

Answer (score 0):

Not in general, no.  The "three-body" problem does not even have closed-form solutions in general, let alone a simplification like this that would make it easy.  It's not clear how you intended to use continued fractions here, but I don't see how that would help.

See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem for more information.